# How to make the top-border of a double-border styled element invisible using FullCalendar's styling

Tags: jquery, css, fullcalendar, styles

```
      isRTL: false,
        firstDay: 1,
        monthNames: ['Januari','Februari','Maart','April','Mei','Juni','Juli','Augustus','September','Oktober','November','December'],
        monthNamesShort: ['Januari','Februari','Maart','April','Mei','Juni','Juli','Augustus','September','Oktober','November','December'], 
        dayNames: ['Zondag','Maandag','Dinsdag','Woensdag','Donderdag','Vrijdag','Zaterdag',],
        dayNamesShort: ['Zondag','Maandag','Dinsdag','Woensdag','Donderdag','Vrijdag','Zaterdag'],        
        slotLabelFormat:'HH:mm',
        allDayText: 'Hele dag',
        // showNonCurrentDates: false,
        fixedWeekCount: false,
        buttonText: {
          prev: "‹",
          next: "›",
          prevYear: "«",
          nextYear: "»",
          today: 'Vandaag',
          month: 'Maand',
          week: 'Week',
          day: 'Dag'
        },
   });
  });


   
  </script>
```

```
  <style type="text/css">
    .fc-body{
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    .fc-highlight{
      background: #71AFE5 !important;
    }
    .fc-day-number{
      float: left !important;
    }
    .fc-unthemed td.fc-today{
      background: none !important; 
    }
    .fc-past{
      background-color: #faf9f8;
      color: black !important;
    }
    .fc-row .fc-content-skeleton td, .fc-row .fc-helper-skeleton td{
      border-color: #ddd;
    }
    .fc-day-header{
      background: royalblue !important;
    }
    .fc td.fc-today{
      border-style: solid !important;
    }
/*    .fc-day-top .fc-wed .fc-today .fc-state-highlight td{
      border-top-color: royalblue !important;
      border-top-width: 8px !important;
      position: absolute !important;
      width: 157px !important;
    }*/
    .fc-day-header span{
      color: white;
      font-weight: 300;
      font-size: 15px;
    }
    .fc-day-top{
      background-color: none !important;
      border-top-width: 0px !important;
      border-top-color: transparent !important;
    }
    .fc-today, .fc-state-highlight {
      border-top-color: royalblue !important;
      border-top-width: 5px !important;
      color: royalblue;
    }
/*    .fc-day-header, .fc-widget-header, .fc-fri   {
      border-top-color: transparent !important;
      border-top-width: 1px !important;
      position: relative !important;
    }*/
  </style>
```

I don't get how to turn the topside of it invisible without affecting any other elements. I've searched far and wide for other answers, but could not find a question similar to mine, especially regarding FC.

Is there a way to get rid of the top-side of a double-border in a FullCalendar element? And if not, is there any actual alternative solution to this question?

Thanks in advance.

---

```js
// your js here and what's missing 

/*      isRTL: false,
        firstDay: 1,
        monthNames: ['Januari','Februari','Maart','April','Mei','Juni','Juli','Augustus','September','Oktober','November','December'],
        monthNamesShort: ['Januari','Februari','Maart','April','Mei','Juni','Juli','Augustus','September','Oktober','November','December'], 
        dayNames: ['Zondag','Maandag','Dinsdag','Woensdag','Donderdag','Vrijdag','Zaterdag',],
        dayNamesShort: ['Zondag','Maandag','Dinsdag','Woensdag','Donderdag','Vrijdag','Zaterdag'],        
        slotLabelFormat:'HH:mm',
        allDayText: 'Hele dag',
        // showNonCurrentDates: false,
        fixedWeekCount: false,
        buttonText: {
          prev: "‹",
          next: "›",
          prevYear: "«",
          nextYear: "»",
          today: 'Vandaag',
          month: 'Maand',
          week: 'Week',
          day: 'Dag'
        },
   });
  });
  */
```

```css
.fc-body{
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    .fc-highlight{
      background: #71AFE5 !important;
    }
    .fc-day-number{
      float: left !important;
    }
    .fc-unthemed td.fc-today{
      background: none !important; 
    }
    .fc-past{
      background-color: #faf9f8;
      color: black !important;
    }
    .fc-row .fc-content-skeleton td, .fc-row .fc-helper-skeleton td{
      border-color: #ddd;
    }
    .fc-day-header{
      background: royalblue !important;
    }
    .fc td.fc-today{
      border-style: solid !important;
    }
/*    .fc-day-top .fc-wed .fc-today .fc-state-highlight td{
      border-top-color: royalblue !important;
      border-top-width: 8px !important;
      position: absolute !important;
      width: 157px !important;
    }*/
    .fc-day-header span{
      color: white;
      font-weight: 300;
      font-size: 15px;
    }
    .fc-day-top{
      background-color: none !important;
      border-top-width: 0px !important;
      border-top-color: transparent !important;
    }
    .fc-today, .fc-state-highlight {
      border-top-color: royalblue !important;
      border-top-width: 5px !important;
      color: royalblue;
    }
/*    .fc-day-header, .fc-widget-header, .fc-fri   {
      border-top-color: transparent !important;
      border-top-width: 1px !important;
      position: relative !important;
    }*/
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.5.1/main.css">
<link href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@5.13.1/css/all.css' rel='stylesheet'>



<div id='calendar'></div>





<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.5.1/main.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" ></script>
```

Comment: Please add working code in https://jsfiddle.net so we can help.

Comment: @Hardik's FullCalendar is a JQuery plugin. I have no idea on how to stuff it in and get it functional with JSFiddle. :/

Comment: here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/a7mad24/jso51pm6/  replace the js and css with yours. eventually update jquery and plugin version if needed

Comment: added a snippet to your question that you need to finish to demonstrate your issue (or delete it if you wish)